# Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: database-design, ms-access, entity-relationship

I'm trying to create a database but in the design process. A bit of background on what is required. I have a table containing a bunch of details concerning customers. This is being imported from an external csv file every month. The data is going to be validated checking the email is valid and then copied to another table in the exact same structure but containing the details that are valid (valid email).

This data being imported is from an online registration (including name, DOB, email) form where customers choose their favourite genre styles based on external data of a list of pre-selected genres. There about 11 genres (also in a csv file). Also in this imported customer data is what each customer has chosen as a recently purchased magazine. This also comes from a magazine csv file with list of the magazines and a contact detail at the publisher.

Using this data I want to based on the customer data link between the music genres and magazine lists for third party suppliers who can view mailing lists and potential customers.

I've attached a jpg file of the erd diagram. I'm having trouble make sure the links between entities are correct. http://img718.imageshack.us/i/erd2.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.

- Invalidated listeners to Listeners is 1 <-> 0..1
- Listeners to Genres: 0..n <-> 0..n

which can be represented as

- Listeners to Listener Genres: 1 <-> 0..n
- Listener Genres to Genres: 0..n <-> 1

and same thing for magazines

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format of your text there in regards to the links between the entities as in what does "1 <-> 0..1" mean?

Comment: it's the whole 1 to 1, 1 to many etc. notation. Each Invalidated Listener corresponds to either 0 or 1 Listeners. Second example: Each Listener listens to anywhere from 0 to n Genres, and each Genre is listened to by 0 to n Listeners.

Comment: This is the attribute design of each table. http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/9893/21312312n.png

Comment: I would suggest 1) get rid of Invalidated Listeners. Just have a "isValid" boolean in Listeners. 2) You don't have to have ListenerGenreId. You can instead use combination of ListenerId and GenreId as primary key (same for magazines). Otherwise looks good

Comment: Ah right, i understand. Ok, those links seem fine enough. The only problem i have is whether the magazine contact to magazine name is 1 to many, or many to 1 relationship, based on the attribute design i just linked to.

Comment: I have 12 magazines currently listed with a contact for each so wouldn't that be 1 to 1 for now? Or just put many magazines to 1 contact incase another contact releases a magazine and has two magazines instead of 1?

Comment: I've edited my design based on your recommendations. Many thanks it's much appreciated. My only query now apart from my above comment is when you mentioned removing listenergenreid and instead using listenerid and genreid, don't I need to ensure I have a primary key in that table, and the same for magazines?

Comment: 1) If you ever anticipate having multiple contacts per magazine, keep it as is, will be harder to change later. 2) You absolutely need a primary key, but it may be a combination of 2 fields and not just a single field. So in this case, you can set primary key to be combination of ListenerId and GenreId. Now, given how i helped you, you click "accept" on my answer and i get some reputation points :)

Comment: Ok, will do, no worries. I meant it's possible that in future there could be multiple magazines per contact. At the current moment there are 11 magazines with 11 contacts. So each contact has a magazine at the moment but it's possible a contact could add another magazine.

Comment: oh i see. What you have now is "one magazine may have multiple contacts." If you want the reverse, kill "magazine id" in contact and add "foreign key: contact id" in magazine.

Comment: Thank you very much! One final matter :P do you know how to combine two foreign keys into a primary like you were mentioning in your previous comment to combine listenerid and genreid into a primary key in Microsoft Access?

Comment: MS Access - no idea. in SQL, you'd say CREATE TABLE ... PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2) and that's it. But that is not really a problem, you can keep your DB as is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated. My first question has been well received. I'll start using this site more when i run into problems :) Thank you again.

Comment: To make a compound PK in Access: Open the table in Design view, select the two (or more) fields, click the Key button (location varies by version). Save.